# CentOSでsudoでyum installができない

Tags: centos, yum

CentOS8で `yum install gcc` を実行するとroot権限を求められたので、`sudo yum install gcc` で実行し直すと以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
repo 'AppStream', 'baseos', 'extras' のキャッシュの同期に失敗しました。このrepoを無視します
一致した引数がありません：gcc
エラー：一致するものがありません
```

しかし、rootユーザーに切り替えてから `yum install gcc` を実行するとgccがインストールできました。なぜ `sudo` ではうまくgccがインストールできないのでしょうか？
なお、`dnf` コマンドでも同じようにしてインストールができません。

CentOS8はVirtualBoxのゲストOSとして動いており、ホストOS側ではプロキシを使っています。
ネットワーク設定はインストールから何もしていないので、そのままになってると思います。

Comment: yum でも dnf でも同様のエラーが発生する事から、HTTP/HTTPS でのアクセスにプロキシサーバを経由している(環境変数 `http_proxy` や `https_proxy` などを設定してる)状況が考えられるのですが、実際にプロキシサーバをお使いでしょうか？

Comment: ホストOSはプロキシサーバを使って外部とつながっていて、これを使ってバーチャルボックスのcentosも通信をしています

Comment: それでは `sudo` コマンドに `-E` オプションを付けて実行するとどうなりますでしょうか。`sudo -E yum install ...`

Comment: `-E` オプションでうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` コマンド実行時に `-E` オプションを付けて実行してみてください。

```
$ sudo -E yum install gcc
```

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61420/centos%e3%81%a7sudo%e3%81%a7yum-install%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment66822_61420) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*